# Is there a way in eclipse to auto generate references/fields into a class for all specified views in a layout?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse to auto generate references/fields into a class for all specified views in a layout?

i.e. click somewhere to auto generate a variable in a specified activity-class, for a view on a layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No I dont think this is possible at this time but you could provide us with a candy eclipse plugin :D